# No Visual Studio .NET Versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I tried everything for solve this. When I open a new project, it only list .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 versions. But I want to 4.5 or newer versions.

I'd try:

- Windows updates
- Visual Studio updates (16.4 to 16.5)
- Repair VS
- Installing .NET packages with VS Installer
- Installing .NET packages with Microsoft site
- Restart (Computer, Visual Studio)
- Reinstalling Visual Studio (with remove everything)
- Reinstalling VS Installer (with remove everything)

Please help

Comment: What is the type of the project?

Comment: Do you see "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK" listed in the Add or Remove Programs list?

Comment: No i don't. But i can see this on BCUninstaller and when i install 4.7.2 Dev pack it returns "already installed".

Comment: Project type is Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

again. I solved this with a little move operation. Many weeks ago I changed program installation folder (moved into other partition). Visual Studio Installer is crazy about this. It created a folders into my new x86 program files folder. Look like:

```
H:\x86 -> this is my default folder


H:\x86\x86....\x86\Refferenced Libraries -> this is created by VSI
```

Whatever, I collected every parts of .NET and i moved it to true folder. It solved.